# Building a Go app with QT statically linked

Tags: qt, go, qml, static-linking, cgo

I want to build a self-contained app using QML and Go.

I compiled QT statically:

```
./configure -static -release -opensource -confirm-license -prefix /home/simon/projects/qt-5.6.1/ -nomake examples -nomake tests -no-cups -no-alsa -no-pulseaudio -no-egl -no-audio-backend -no-gstreamer -no-sql-mysql -no-sql-sqlite -skip qtwebengine -skip multimedia -skip qtwebsockets -skip qtwebchannel  -qt-zlib -qt-libpng -qt-libjpeg -qt-freetype -qt-harfbuzz -no-libproxy -qt-pcre -qt-xcb -qt-xkbcommon-x11 -dbus-runtime -no-mtdev -no-openssl -no-glib -no-xcursor -no-xfixes -no-xrandr -no-xinerama -no-xinput -no-iconv -no-largefile -skip qtwayland -skip qtwinextras -skip qtsvg -skip qtsensors -skip qtcanvas3d -skip qtconnectivity -no-icu
make -j2
make install
```

I compiled my app with:

```
go build --ldflags '-extldflags "-L/home/simon/projects/qt-5.6.1/lib -l qtpcre -l poly2tri -lqxcb -l qtharfbuzzng -l GL -l icuuc -l icuio -l icui18n -Wl,--no-as-needed -ldl"'
```

What I get is an executable statically linked with QT and dynamically linked with libc/opengl/others:

```
ldd frontend 

linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fffa295d000)

libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f7006012000)

libpthread.so.0 => /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f7005df5000)

libdl.so.2 => /usr/lib/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f7005bf1000)

libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/libGL.so.1 (0x00007f7005980000)

libicuuc.so.57 => /usr/lib/libicuuc.so.57 (0x00007f70055d8000)

libicuio.so.57 => /usr/lib/libicuio.so.57 (0x00007f70053ca000)

libicui18n.so.57 => /usr/lib/libicui18n.so.57 (0x00007f7004f50000)

libm.so.6 => /usr/lib/libm.so.6 (0x00007f7004c4c000)

libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f7004a36000)

libc.so.6 => /usr/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007f7004695000)

/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f7006399000)

libexpat.so.1 => /usr/lib/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007f7004469000)

libxcb-dri3.so.0 => /usr/lib/libxcb-dri3.so.0 (0x00007f7004266000)

libxcb-present.so.0 => /usr/lib/libxcb-present.so.0 (0x00007f7004063000)

libxcb-randr.so.0 => /usr/lib/libxcb-randr.so.0 (0x00007f7003e53000)

libxcb-xfixes.so.0 => /usr/lib/libxcb-xfixes.so.0 (0x00007f7003c4b000)

libxcb-render.so.0 => /usr/lib/libxcb-render.so.0 (0x00007f7003a3d000)

libxcb-shape.so.0 => /usr/lib/libxcb-shape.so.0 (0x00007f7003839000)

libxcb-sync.so.1 => /usr/lib/libxcb-sync.so.1 (0x00007f7003632000)

libxshmfence.so.1 => /usr/lib/libxshmfence.so.1 (0x00007f700342f000)

libglapi.so.0 => /usr/lib/libglapi.so.0 (0x00007f7003201000)

libXext.so.6 => /usr/lib/libXext.so.6 (0x00007f7002fef000)

libXdamage.so.1 => /usr/lib/libXdamage.so.1 (0x00007f7002dec000)

libXfixes.so.3 => /usr/lib/libXfixes.so.3 (0x00007f7002be6000)

libX11-xcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/libX11-xcb.so.1 (0x00007f70029e4000)

libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/libX11.so.6 (0x00007f70026a2000)

libxcb-glx.so.0 => /usr/lib/libxcb-glx.so.0 (0x00007f7002486000)

libxcb-dri2.so.0 => /usr/lib/libxcb-dri2.so.0 (0x00007f7002281000)

libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007f7002058000)

libXxf86vm.so.1 => /usr/lib/libXxf86vm.so.1 (0x00007f7001e52000)

libdrm.so.2 => /usr/lib/libdrm.so.2 (0x00007f7001c43000)

libicudata.so.57 => /usr/lib/libicudata.so.57 (0x00007f70001c7000)

libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/libXau.so.6 (0x00007f6ffffc3000)

libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007f6fffdbd000)
```

But when I try to run it:

```
./frontend 

2016/06/13 19:49:18 .:0: QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() ignoring "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3" since plugins are disabled in static builds

2016/06/13 19:49:18 .:0: This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb"

in "".

Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

SIGABRT: abort

PC=0x7f85aa7fc295 m=0

signal arrived during cgo execution

goroutine 1 [syscall, locked to thread]:

runtime.cgocall(0x7d9df0, 0xc82004be10, 0x0)

    /usr/lib/go/src/runtime/cgocall.go:123 +0x11b fp=0xc82004bde8 sp=0xc82004bdb8

gopkg.in/qml%2ev1._Cfunc_newGuiApplication()

    ??:0 +0x36 fp=0xc82004be10 sp=0xc82004bde8

gopkg.in/qml%2ev1.Run(0xc82000b240, 0x0, 0x0)

    /home/simon/go/src/gopkg.in/qml.v1/bridge.go:55 +0x10f fp=0xc82004be68 sp=0xc82004be10

main.main()

    /home/simon/go/src/github.com/ProtonMail/Desktop-Import/frontend/main.go:52 +0x2d3 fp=0xc82004bf50 sp=0xc82004be68

runtime.main()

    /usr/lib/go/src/runtime/proc.go:188 +0x2b0 fp=0xc82004bfa0 sp=0xc82004bf50

runtime.goexit()

    /usr/lib/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1998 +0x1 fp=0xc82004bfa8 sp=0xc82004bfa0

goroutine 17 [syscall, locked to thread]:

runtime.goexit()

    /usr/lib/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1998 +0x1

rax    0x0

rbx    0x7ffc69a64030

rcx    0x7f85aa7fc295

rdx    0x6

rdi    0x359b

rsi    0x359b

rbp    0x407b270

rsp    0x7ffc69a63cd8

r8     0x211f1e0

r9     0x8

r10    0x8

r11    0x202

r12    0x7ffc69a63ff0

r13    0x18

r14    0x7ffc69a64040

r15    0x7ffc69a64000

rip    0x7f85aa7fc295

rflags 0x202

cs     0x33

fs     0x0

gs     0x0
```

What's going on?

Comment: I would assume the warning/error message `plugins are disabled in static builds` has something to do with it

Comment: You need to statically link your application with relevant plugins.

Comment: @buka-ober That's what I'm trying to do with `-lqxcb` (I have `libqxcb.a`) but maybe I missed something? How to do that?